# How to identify component vectors correctly?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, vectors

Firstly I'm sorry for asking this very basic (& seemingly repeated) question but I want some more insight on it.
The main question is this only: [Velocity of a ring tied to an inextensible rope](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/422494/velocity-of-a-ring-tied-to-an-inextensible-rope)

[image: Diagram]

Now I HAVE read the accepted answer and Yes MATHEMATICALLY its CORRECT.
But............

- It doesn't answers why questioner's following logic is incorrect:

> The rope is pulling the ring at an angle so only the component of the
> the velocity of the rope in the direction of movement of ring should
> act make it move, which ultimately makes the velocity of ring as ${v}_{ring}={v}_{rope}\cos\left(\theta \right)$

- Also it seems counterintuitive to say that velocity of ring has a component along rope whereas it sounds more reasonable to say that velocity of rope has a component along the ring because ORIGINALLY the force is applied on rope only. So at at intuitive level, how to make sense of this?
- Even if ${v}_{rope}={v}_{ring}\cos\left(\theta \right)$ is correct, is there any shorter way to find out the CORRECT components of a vector in such confusing situations? I don't think while solving mechanics problems one would go through such long process just to identify the component vectors?

Comment: [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/648788/305718) may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that

$$v_{ring}=v_{rope}\cos (\theta)$$

is incorrect is that this assumes $\theta$ is constant, which it is not. Once you realise this, the correct derivation is quite straightforward. If the distance of the ring from the pulley is $y$ and the horizontal distance (along the bar) is $x$ then:

$y^2=x^2+\text{ constant}
\\ \displaystyle  \Rightarrow 2y \frac {dy}{dt}=2x\frac {dx}{dt}
\\ \displaystyle \Rightarrow v_{rope}=\frac x y v_{ring} = v_{ring}\cos (\theta)$

Although this result looks superficially like “taking components” it is better not to think of it like this.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I think those were the 2 points I was missing, 1)θ isn't constant and 2) _**"Although this result looks superficially like “taking components” it is better not to think of it like this"**_